# Using NeoLoad to test ZK application

Tags: zk, neoload

I am trying to use NeoLoad 5.2 to record test scenario for ZK application.

Unfortunately, it looks like some operations are not recorded. For example:

- Login and password of the login form are not shown among requests
- Population of combo boxes is not shown

I prepared ZK app to generate repeatable components and desktops ids.

Does somebody has such experience? Should I configure NeoLoad or ZK application in some special way to record all the data exchange which happens?

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue that the recording did not have any source (empty body). Luckily the play back did have returned code which we used for correlation and validation. Does seem to be a bug in the toolset but we bypassed the issue.